# Why did this integral return $0 = 0$ when applying $2$ Pythagorean identities instead of $1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Had this question on a homework the other day $\int \sin^3x \cos^2x \ \mathrm dx$ pretty simple right but upon my first try through it I turned $\int \sin x \sin^2x \cos^2x \ \mathrm dx$ into $\int \sin x(1-\cos^2x)(1-\sin^2x)\ \mathrm dx$

Now when I broke this all down I got 0 = 0 which I thought was really interesting because this all seemed like I wasnt really breaking any rules?
But if I just do $\int \sin x(1-\cos^2x)\cos^2x \ \mathrm dx$ and substitute then you get an answer really easily. I guess im just curious as to if something above was not allowed? I checked the algebra after breaking it down a bunch and it all seemed sound. Sorry just a little curious as to what it even means

**Edit**:

If you break down the 2 Pythagorean identities equation you eventually get

$\int \sin^3x \cos^2x \ \mathrm dx = \int \sin x \ \mathrm dx - \int \sin^3x \ \mathrm dx- \int \sin x \cos^2x \ \mathrm dx + \int \sin^3x \cos^2x \ \mathrm dx$. If you subtract the $\int \sin^3x\cos^2x\ \mathrm dx$ from both side you get

$$0 = \int \sin x \ \mathrm dx  - \int \sin^3x \ \mathrm dx - \int \sin x\cos^2x  \ \mathrm dx$$

which then breaks down to $0 = 0$

Just curious as to how that's possible or if I messed up a rule?

Comment: You didn't have an equality or equation to begin with, so how come you got $\;0=0\;$ ?

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding what you're trying to ask.  You've obviously put work into understanding your question so I'm sure a number of us will be willing to help, but making your question clearer would be very helpful.

By the way, check the MathJax tutorial for how to express trigonometric functions.

Comment: I'm not worried about getting $0=0$, but if I'd got $0=1$ then I would be worried!

Comment: [This PDF](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-TrigonometIntegrals_Stu.pdf) might helps you to solve those type of trigonometric integrals.

Comment: hey yall I added an edit for what I did when solving, just wondering if that is not legal algebraically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt do anything wrong. If you start with an expression and then using algebraic manipulation you get $0=0$ (or $n=n$) that means the expression you began with is true or this case it means you didnt make any mistakes

Notice that the value of integral is not zero

Comment: oh ok interesting thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x(\cos^2 x)(\sin^2 x)\\\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)(1-\cos^2x)\\\sin x(1 - \sin^2 x - \cos^2 x + \sin^2x\cos^2 x) \\ \sin x(\sin^2 x\cos^2x)$

The double substitution takes you back to where you started.